# How to apply patches to phantomjs port in FreeBSD 9?

Tags: freebsd, phantomjs

I have installed FreeBSD 9 and I need to install [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org). It is available in `/usr/ports/lang/phantomjs` but the version is 1.0 while I need a more recent version. There is a [patch](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/query-pr.cgi?pr=163912) to update to version 1.4.1 but I don't know how to apply this patch. I've googled this and read the [FreeBSD Porter's Handbook](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/porters-handbook/slow-patch.html) several times but I'm still lost.

Also there is no entry about phantomjs in `/usr/ports/UPDATING` file.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update your port tree. Run:

```
portsnap fetch update
```

If you want to keep your port tree updated on a regular basis you can create a periodic script.
This is the script I use on my dev machine, `/usr/local/etc/periodic/weekly/910.portsnap`

```
#!/bin/sh -
#
#

# If there is a global system configuration file, suck it in.
#
if [ -r /etc/defaults/periodic.conf ]
then
    . /etc/defaults/periodic.conf
    source_periodic_confs
fi

case "$weekly_portsnap_enable" in
    [Yy][Ee][Ss])
        echo ""
        echo "Updating ports tree via portsnap:"

        portsnap cron update | grep -v /;;

    *)  rc=0;;
esac

exit $rc
```

Don't forget to `chmod+x 910.portsnap` and add `weekly_portsnap_enable="YES"` to your `/etc/periodic.conf` file.

Comment: If ever anyone is interested in running phantomjs 1.6.1, intructions provided at http://code.google.com/p/phantomjs/issues/detail?id=597#c1 works perfectly with FreeBSD9 and clang.

Unfortunately, you'll have to build by hand, as port tree only contains version 1.4, which the subbject of the question.